# Can i code a surface difference between two XYZ's in Python?

Tags: python, xyz, scipy

I would tend to utilize ArcGIS to perform surface difference between two TIN's or Terrains but my recent attempts have been too costly computationally. Instead, what I would like to accomplish is to perform a surface difference between two raw XYZ files and produce an output XYZ file. Is there a mathematical equation (via Python code) that I can use to generate this desired output? Obviously it would be focused on the difference in elevation (Z) of one file versus the other.

Once i have the new XYZ file, i would just proceed to create a TIN or Terrain of this XYZ file.

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish something similar. But trying to calculate difference between two interpolated grids. The grids are of different shapes, so cannot use np.subtract to calculate the difference. Any help on how to calculate the difference? #create two interpolated grids from two set of xyz points and calculate difference ixx = np.array(self.ix) iyy = np.array(self.iy) izz = np.array(self.iz) iminx = min(ixx.flat) imaxx = max(ixx.flat) iminy = min(iyy.flat) imaxy = max(iyy.flat) # post surface - get extents pxx = np.array(self.px) pyy = np.array(self.py) pzz = np.array(self.pz) pminx = mi

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/127180)

Answer (score 1):

You could a look at scipy (maybe numpy/mathplotlib). The basic problem might be that the step between your 2 XYZ files is not regular. In any case, I suppose you will at least compute a similar regular grid of points (X1,Y1 = X2,Y2) to be able to compare Z1 vs Z2.

See here maybe ?
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/interpolate.html or here : http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html#scipy.interpolate.griddata

Another idea : you might want to use raster files instead of TIN, it could be easier. Once you have one raster interpolated for layer 1, with Spatial Analyst, you can query the created raster to add the interpolated Z coordinate to the  XYZ points of layer 2. You will not need to create another raster this way, and you will be able to compute the Z1-Z2 value.

See here : https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/extract-values-to-points.htm

Comment: Any idea on how close XY's need to be in order to calculate a Z difference?

Comment: I would say they need to be the same, whatever step you choose in the end, but maybe there's other methods I didn't think of. Are you dealing with LIDAR data ?

Comment: I'm dealing with single and multi-beam data. Ok so X and Y need to be completely identical on both files.

Comment: It's a difficult problem. You might want to cut your work areas in smaller areas if you can't find a solution.

Comment: I think i will just keep using Rasters in ArcGIS. A co-worker suggested using Fledermaus to generate the desired XYZ and then process it in ArcGIS.

Comment: Fledermaus and Arcgis seem to communicate : http://gisandscience.com/2012/06/08/fledermaus-and-arcgis-integration/ and http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/maritime/bathymetry

Comment: Very interesting. I wonder what is the current state of integration.